# Why async actions have a currying?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I wanted to know if there is a reason why async actions are like currying functions instead of an arrow function with two parameters

```
const asyncAction = () => dispatch => {
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly curried.  The important part is that a function is passed into `dispatch`, like this:

```
const thunkFunction = (dispatch, getState) => {
    // do useful stuff with dispatch and getState        
};
store.dispatch(thunkFunction);
```

But, to be consistent with the rest of good Redux code structure, we use "action creator" functions to encapsulate the process of creating whatever it is we are going to pass to `dispatch`:

```
const thunkFunction = someThunkActionCreator(a, b, c);
store.dispatch(thunkFunction);
```

That way, when we use this in a component, it doesn't even know that there's anything special about the prop function that it's calling:

```
this.props.someThunkActionCreator(a, b, c);
```